# can't install magento2 extension from backend. Why?

Tags: php, magento, backend, magento2, magento2.2

I have installed magento 2.2.2 successfully. Now I trying Installed some extension from magento admin panel using web setup wizard option. I Find my extension and proceed to install. But it's stop on third step. Display don't any error.[image]

here is third step.
[image]

Now, magento stay here. Please let me know what I need to do now?
I am new In magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might not have `cron` set. Set a `magento cron` and run it every minute. Otherwise just run `cron` commands on SSH couple of times you will see the more messages then.

> php bin/magento cron:run 
>   php bin/magneto setup:cron:run 
>   php update/cron.php

This is because Magento uses `cron` to show the updated message.